# Getting data between certain dates for the entries which are not present before the time period mentioned

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this date set table:

```
Product     Entry_Date
1-A         18-02-2020
2-A         19-02-2020
1-A         23-02-2020
3-C         25-02-2020
4-D         26-02-2020
2-A         27-02-2020
```

I need those products which have Entry_Date between 23rd to 27th Feb BUT do not have entries before. 
For eg. the output should be

```
Product
3-C
4-D
```

I tried two approaches:
This works:

```
select Product 
from table a join (select Product, min(Entry_date) as min_date from table) b on a.Product = b.Product
where Entry_date between '23-02-2020' and '27-02-2020'
and b.min_date >='23-02-2020'
```

and this does not:

```
select Product
from table 
where Entry_Date between '23-02-2020' and '27-02-2020'
group by 1
having min(Entry_Date)>='23-02-2020'
```

Is there any elegant way of doing this. Why does the second method does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and `min()` in the `having` clause:

```
select product
from t
group by product
having min(Entry_Date) between '2020-02-23' and '2020-02-27';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bbac110757bf8486388fc63ea657bea2) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that I also fixed your date constants so they are YYYY-MM-DD standard.

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working. It gives me all the products

Comment: @SharadGupta . . . There was  typo.  Does the corrected version work?

Comment: I realized there was a typo and had used the code the same as above. Didn't work

Comment: @SharadGupta . . . This cannot give you products which have an entry date before '2020-02-23' . . . unless these are not stored as dates.  I added a db<>fiddle, illustrating that this code works on the data in your question.